# Retrofit2 parse simple string array

Tags: android, retrofit

Stucked with parsing server response like:

```
[
    "5",
    "2"
]
```

**OR**

```
[
    "5"
]
```

So it is dynamic and can be one value or 2+ values in response. Only numbers in response.

**I am getting:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

on my `callTest.execute();` with any types:

```
    Response<String[]> newPostResponse = callTest.execute();
    Response<ArrayList<String>> newPostResponse = callTest.execute();
    Response<List<String>> newPostResponse = callTest.execute();
```

**PS: this retrofit method working in AsyncTask:**

```
class mATloadF extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private Context mContext;

    public mATloadF (Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        thoseRetrofitMethod();
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //some code
    }
}
```

**PPS:** I described data from server as is:
[image]

Comment: IMHO, `JSONArray` response should be in `JSONObject`. the response should be started with `JSONObject`

Comment: obviously you are not getting this json which you were posted ...

Comment: @RumitPatel, ok, thanks, I will ask to change response for starting from `JSONObject`